# Swift UI - Collapsible section headers

Tags: swiftui

I have a list with sections headers on two views. One view has the section headers as collapsible, the other doesn't.

Both use pretty much the same code, what defines if a section header is collapsible?

Code for the one that doesn't collapse

```
List {
        ForEach(cards) { section in
            let header: String = nameForSectionHeader(sectionID: section.id)
            Section(header: Text(header)) {
                ForEach(section) { card in
                    NavigationLink(destination: CardView(card: card)) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(card.imageName ?? "")
                                .renderingMode(.original)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 50.0)
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                if let name = card.name, let id = card.cardID {
                                    Text("\(id) - \(name)")
                                }
                                Text("Owned: \(card.owned)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the code for the one that does

```
List {
            ForEach(cards) { section in
                let header: String = nameForSectionHeader(sectionID: section.id)
                Section(header: Text(header)) {
                    ForEach(section) { card in
                        NavigationLink(destination: CardView(card: card)) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                if let name = card.name, let id = card.cardID {
                                    Text("\(id) - \(name)")
                                }
                                if let set = card.set, let setName = set.name {
                                    Text("Set: \(setName)")
                                }
                                if card.owned > 0 {
                                    Text("Owned: \(card.owned)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(lightGreen)
        }
```

Comment: You just a Boolean that you use inside the ForEach loop : if collapse {card collapsed view} else {card not collapsed view}

Comment: Doesn't help. As I said, one does it autmoatically. I've since found out its because one view has a navigationview and one doesn't. I can't add a navigation view to the second otherwise I end up with a large blank space at the top

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood you. Id it a Mac or iOS app ? As on on Mac you have [collapsible()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section/collapsible(_:)) for section.

Comment: iOS app. In the latest SwiftUI it appears as though any lists contained within a NavigationView become automatically collapsible. My issue is my previous view has a NavigationView so can't add another into this view otherwise I end up with a massive blank space at the top of the view